# Is Dart what we use to code Angulardart?

Tags: javascript, dart, angular-dart, dart-webui

Hey Guys I was looking up Dart and Im a bit confused on what the site offers, as I see a two things, Dart and AngularDart. Im from an Angular background and when i went through the AngularDart Docs it kinda resembled the work I did with Angular so my question is What is Dart actually and What is it in relation to AngularDart And What is AngularDart ? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) is a programming language. There are two "flavors" of Angular, [one for TypeScript](https://angular.io/) and [one for Dart](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular). If you use AngularDart, you are writing an Angular application in the Dart language.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense now. Tx